# Website->Server PHP Socket Refused, but .NET Client Connects

Tags: c#, php, sockets, tcp

The program that is running on the server is listening for a connection. It uses TcpListener from .NET. Using netstat, the port is listening.

When using a tester data sender, the connection is accepted and the data is processed. To do the same with PHP sockets does not work properly. It returns errno 111.

Looking for an answer amidst some of the PHP-related socket questions, it was said that it could be one of three things: no http server, TCP queue full, or the firewall.

Web server

```php
$port = 6000;
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_connect($socket, "remote.ip", $port);
socket_send($socket, $data, strlen($data), 1);
socket_close($socket);
```

Server

```cs
tcp = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
tcp.Start(backlog);
sock = tcp.AcceptSocket();
```

> Warning: socket_connect(): unable to connect [111]: Connection refused in 
>   page.php on line 10
>
> Warning: socket_send(): unable to write to socket [32]: Broken pipe in 
>   page.php on line 11

Comment: Are you testing connecting from localhost?

Comment: In the form of a debug program that connects locally and sends data, yes (for c#). I haven't tried using PHP sockets locally though...

Comment: I'd suggest trying your PHP code locally.

Comment: Local attempts are working. The main attempts for this question are from a web host, and locally was done using IIS.